# IMU-Camera Time Synchronisation on Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, synchronization

I'm using MPU6050 IMU with the raspberry pi. I want to get data at a required frequency, for example, 200 Hz that is I want data at every 0.005 seconds. How do I go on to accomplish this? I'm using i2c for serial communication. Feel free to suggest any other method by which I can get this done.

Comment: More suitable for [superuser](https://superuser.com)